# Torch is running successfully in VSCode but gives error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, anaconda, torch

I installed torch after creating the anaconda virtual environment using the following commands:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

Then I run the following commands in VSCode successfully:

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

However, the above commands in the Jupyter notebook return the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

I used the same Anaconda virtual environment for both. I have windows 10 OS.

Can anyone tell me why should there be an error in the Jupyter notebook? and how to fix this error?
Should I install the torch using conda but then should I remove the pip installation?

Comment: If you installed Jupyter using conda, then you should install other packages (like torch) using conda too. Do not mix the two installation systems, this leads to many issues, some are obvious (like this one), some will waste you hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to uninstall PyTorch using pip, since it says torch is not installed while it is clearly installed?

Comment: Conda installation for pytorch results in the following error:  failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve

Comment: This is not an error yet, just a warning. These kind of things happen when you mix up `conda` and `pip` (`conda` cannot solve things properly because there are things it did not install). The easiest way forward is to create a clean conda environment from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the numpy jupyter notebook that supports PyTorch,

launch your notebook again while in you're in virtual env path

Comment: How may I install that? I could not find much information about numpy jupyter notebook on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Your VSCode and jupyer notebook use different environments. To get a quick look at which packages your Jupyter notebook includes, directly input 'pip list' in the coding line.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Then you will find that 'torch' is not there.
To overcome this, just install the packages that you need for the Jupyter notebook
in the coding line as 'pip install torch torchvision torchaudio'.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Izj.png